# Pl/ SQL update trigger to update the ranking upon an update operation on a table

Tags: sql

Given table_player

```
Players.      Score
A.            34
B.            45
C.            34
D.            20
```

i want to use an update triggers which automatically updates the rank of a player when the score of an individual changes and i want also this rank column to persist as new-column in table.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a good use for triggers because 1) you'd have to select from the table that you're inserting into and 2) you'd potentially have to update all rows in the table every time you insert a new row. These are both likely to cause mutating data errors unless you create a really complex scheme to avoid them.

However, a view can effectively accomplish the same thing. The only difference is that the view doesn't store the data, it would simply do the ranking calculation each time you access the table. If your database supports analytic functions, this would be as simple as:

```
CREATE VIEW table_player_rank AS
SELECT player, score, rank() OVER (ORDER BY score) AS player_rank 
FROM table_player;
```